# zabbix-java-gateway failed to start in Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS

Tags: zabbix

java-gateway in Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS to monitor Java based applications.But i was not able to start zabbix-java-gateway.I am getting below error.

Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
zabbix_java_gateway[34235]: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/zabbix/gateway/JavaGat

**Os Details:**
Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS

**Zabbix server details:**
zabbix_server (Zabbix) 3.4.10

**zabbix-java-gateway version:**
Version: 1:3.4.13-1+bionic

Answer (score 0):

You run with a Java Version less the Version which was used to compile the classes

```
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/zabbix/gateway/JavaGat
```

Update your Java version